# How can I make it so that the displayed element receives the scroll events?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a website where I  have created "pages". Each page is essentially a container with nested elements. I have coded a fading effect on my page where I set all non-visible pages to 0 opacity and the visible opacity of the displayed container to 1. I have a working algorithm that can switch pages by transitioning the opacity from 1 to 0 and then make another page transition nicely.

However, two pages have a scrollable area like so,

```
            <div id="x-container" style="opacity: 0;">
                <div id="x-content" class="container-fluid" style="overflow: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
```

What is occuring is that the scrollable area events are only being received on the last created html element because it is on top, with an opacity on 0. Therefore if I cannot receive scrollable events on a page created before the last one, despite being the only visible scrollable area it is not receiving the events. How can I make it so that only the html elements that are "visible" i.e. opacity of 1 should receive the events, not the invisible elements.

Comment: Can you show any picture of what you wanted and what is happening?

Comment: @KunalTanwar Well simply put, I have an html element with an opacity of 0, on top of another html element with an opacity of 1. Both have scrollable elements attached to them but it is only being received on the last html scrollable html element created, but ideally, I would want it on the current "visible" scrollable element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use z-index in CSS to make the scrolling div behind the one you wanted then position it to make it like swallowing it [Demo](https://js-demo.com/index.php?ref=65c21d77c225)

Comment: Z-index for the displayed element works, cheers.